# How get values as integer in formGroup.value in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, dynamicform

I make a form using [DynamicForm](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) it work perfect but when try to get the values using `form.value` or `form.getRawValue()` all files are return like string, how I make to the `number` files as return as `integer` in the JSON file

**Example**

actually I get a JSON like this

```
{
  "name": "home",
  "age": "12"
}
```

but I need this:

```
{
  "name": "home",
  "age": 12
}
```

**EDIT**

The formControl constructor

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  name : new FormControl(undefined  || '', Validators.required),
  age  : new FormControl(undefined  || '')
});
```

Comment: did you put type="number" in template?

Comment: @kit yes I defind the type="number" and the validation work but even so return string;

Comment: hmm.., what is the first param you put to FormControl constructor?

Comment: @kit edit the quesiton with the constructor, the first param is `undefined`because don't have default value

Comment: I think understand my problem always take as default value ' ' thanks so much for the help; but how can define the constructor of a integer if not have initial value?

Comment: maybe try null, but it's just a guess

Comment: @kit thanks it work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try putting null into first param of FormControl

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to convert input type="number" to an integer with an array of controls using angular dynamic forms.

This snipped returns the actual control that was changed.

```
const formArray = this.parentFormGroup.controls['obligationList'] as FormArray
formArray.controls.forEach(control => {
    control.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(800)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(() => control.patchValue({amountPayable: parseInt(control.value['amountPayable'], 10)}, {emitEvent : false}))
})
```

This will return a value of type integer.